# Configure local Docker container and connect to it remotely from another network

Tags: docker, remote-access

So I have a local Docker container with Airflow runnin on Windows 10. I wonder, could I remotely connect to it from another computer running also on Windows 10 from another network? And how should I configure it in terms of security? I'm literally working with Docker first evening and kinda really lost, will appreciate any help!

Comment: you can expose ports to local host as part of the `docker run` command and then as long as you can access those ports over the network you should be fine.

Comment: @joshbeauregard but what about security ? In theory anyone who got IP and port can connect?

Comment: @NikitaBudilovskiy at the end of the day you're running airflow, refer to [the airflow documentation related to security aspects](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/index.html).

Comment: @NikitaBudilovskiy airflow has an auth system